# Join two tables by 2 keys

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am using Microsoft Excel 2016. And I have 2 tables on different sheets.

```
sheet1.tbl1 {
key1,
key2,
val1,
fun1,
fun2
}

sheet2.tbl2 {
key1,
key2,
val1,
val2
}
```

I want to bring values to `sheet1.tbl1` from `sheet2.tbl2` using formula or other methods.
Specifically, join by `key1, key2` and bring `val1, val2` from `sheet2.tbl2` to `fun1, fun2` from `sheet1.tbl1` respectively. Keys are both unique in both tables, so first match will do.

I have tried formula

```
=INDEX(rls, MATCH(tbl1[[key1]:[key2]], tbl2[key1]:[key2]], 0),3)
```

But it doesn't work.

I also don't want to use extensions, I want to achieve that using built in functionality. And preferably using table column syntax (`tbl1[[key1]:[key2]]`).

Comment: I understand your desire to avoid external tools. Do you think [**what is on the Data tab**](https://youtu.be/M_jIsnksv7I) is "built in functionality"?

Comment: Yes, I have Data tab. The problem with external tools is that I have to share that Excel file with my coworkers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the lookup value in your `MATCH` needs to be a value and not an array. One way to solve is to build a helper column in tbl2 that combines key1 and key2 and then do your `MATCH` on that (or reduce to t `VLOOKUP`).

Comment: Try replacing your : with a &. Basically create a single cell lookup value by concatenating key1 and key2 as a string.

Comment: You might need the @ modifier too to make it act per row/cell rather than per array column.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is in the key combo in the second table. It makes it hard to use `VLOOKUP()` for example. But is is no particular problem for `INDEX/MATCH` or `XLOOKUP()`.

For example:

```
=XLOOKUP($A1:$A9&"|"&$B1:$B9,  $H$20:$H$28&"|"&$I$20:$I$28,  J20:J28,,0)
```

You combine the keys using the union operator `&`, separating them with an unexpected to exist in the existing data character like `|`. (You can pick a character, then do a search for it in the keys to make sure it is unused.) This is so that unexpected duplications do not occur. Example: one key pair is `Add` and `ress` while another is `Ad` and `dress`. With a character in between one gets `Add|ress` and `Ad|dress` rather than two instances of `Address`.

Doing the combining is straightforward for `XLOOKUP()` and `MATCH()` (the half of `INDEX/MATCH` in which you do it). Both can also easily handle using the arrays for those parts, so you can make a single formula.

In current versions, they will `SPILL` which works out nicely. In older versions (you tagged with 2016's) they will not so you would need to use either `{CSE}` entry or copy and paste down the column as needed.

For newer versions, `XLOOKUP()` has a simple and obvious (nice for maintenance) formula. For the older versions, `INDEX/MATCH` sacrifices little:

```
=INDEX($J$20:$J$28,  MATCH($A1:$A9&"|"&$B1:$B9,  $H$20:$H$28&"|"&$I$20:$I$28,,0))
```

Given you need to handle both, that's the one to use.

Neither formula likes a two column target range, so (in these formulas) J20:K28 is not available.

(*But naturally, someone may know a nice method to make it available!)*

There's a nice method using `FILTER/FILTER` but you cannot use it with Excel-2016 users so it won't help you today. Could be a helpful technique in future workbooks though:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(H20:K28,SORT(A1:A9&"|"&B1:B9)=SORT(H20:H28&"|"&I20:I28)),{0,0,1,1})
```

The inner `FILTER()` chooses the data. Of course, the lists of keys are  almost certainly not in the same order (or "=F12, =F13, =F14, etc. would be close to working, eh?). So use `SORT()` on each key combining array to put them in the same order. If there are key pairs in the second table that are not in the first, you'd need to either drop them or choose a different path.

The outer `FILTER` then works a lot like `INDEX()` can when using an array constant to choose the columns (or rows) to output (nd you could use `INDEX()` instead, but not as easily. `FILTER()` uses the simple array constant as a "show column/don't show column" feature. So you only output the two columns you wish to output.

It has the nicety of providing a multi-dimensional output including `SPILL`-ing so one formula in one cell and you have your whole output.

You could even use `FILTERXML()` which 2016 users would have, but though it is a very nicely clever use of it (especially as the method would build both column's arrays in the single XPATH) `usually`, in this case it would just be a very basic low-level number crunching exercise. Kludgy... "to the max." And could run into problems with internal array string length.

This is not even to mention the helper column route (for the combined keys), or its cousin, putting the combined keys into Named Ranges to make them easily addressable.

I would recommend the `INDEX/MATCH` method for your mix of users.